# My Bluetooth app doesn't discover devices at times

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have developed this android app (using tutorials available online) that searches for the bluetooth devices nearby & shows them in a `ListView`.

The problems I have with my app are:

- It doesn't search all the devices nearby. If there are 6 Bluetooth devices kept very close to the phone, at max the app detects 4. However, the actual Bluetooth of my android phone (the one that can be accessed from Phone Settings) displays all 6 of them.
- Sometimes even the devices that were discovered before don't show up in the next round of search.

I'm wondering if it has something to do with my code or the Bluetooth devices themselves. But then again, my phone's BT detects all of them at all times.

Here's my **MainActivity.java**

```
package vertex2016.mvjce.edu.bluealert;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public BluetoothAdapter BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    private int REQ_CODE = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void connect(View v)
    {
        if(BA == null)
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "System Doesn't Support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        else if(!BA.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBT, REQ_CODE);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ALREADY ON!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            searchBTDevices();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode!=RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TURNED ON!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            searchBTDevices();
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"FAILED TO ENABLE BLUETOOTH", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }




    public void searchBTDevices()
    {
        Thread searchThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent searchBT = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchBTDevice.class);
                startActivity(searchBT);
            }
        };
        searchThread.start();
    }
}
```

Here's my **SearchBTDevice.java** (this one actually performs the search operation)

```
package vertex2016.mvjce.edu.bluealert;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Set;

public class SearchBTDevice extends AppCompatActivity {

    public BluetoothAdapter BlueAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    public ArrayAdapter PairedArrayAdapter;
    public ArrayAdapter BTArrayAdapter;

    public ListView devicesFound;



   private final BroadcastReceiver BTReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver(){

       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
       {
           String action = intent.getAction();

           if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
           {
               BluetoothDevice btd = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                BTArrayAdapter.add(btd.getName() + "\t" + btd.getAddress() + "\n");

           }


       }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        this.registerReceiver(BTReceiver,filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        this.unregisterReceiver(BTReceiver);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_btdevice);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


       searchBTDevices();


    }


    public void searchBTDevices()
    {
        if(!BlueAdapter.startDiscovery())
            Toast.makeText(SearchBTDevice.this, "Failed to Start Discovery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(SearchBTDevice.this, "Discovery Startred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        BTArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        devicesFound = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.searchpagelistView);
        devicesFound.setAdapter(BTArrayAdapter);

    }


}
```

Here's my **activity_search_btdevice.xml** for the Search activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="vertex2016.mvjce.edu.bluealert.SearchBTDevice">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_search_btdevice" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here's my **content_search_btdevice.xml** for Search activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="vertex2016.mvjce.edu.bluealert.SearchBTDevice"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_search_btdevice">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/searchpageimageView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/bluealert_bg"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/searchpagelistView"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Nearby Devices"
            android:id="@+id/nearbydevicestextView"
            android:layout_above="@+id/searchpagelistView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#E7F1FA"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="vertex2016.mvjce.edu.bluealert">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/bluealerticon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SearchBTDevice"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_btdevice"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="vertex2016.mvjce.edu.bluealert.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How can I make my app perform the way the Bluetooth in my phone performs?

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: it could be the bluetooth devices, you could have are different bluetooth: sometime it is Regular Bluetooth (below 3.0 version) or Bluetooth Le (above 4.0)

Comment: How come my phone's bluetooth detects all of them at all times, but not my app?

Comment: Because your phone handle both of them, but in your case yi think you only handle 3.0